# How can I filter documents that don't have a list of keys?

Tags: rethinkdb

Say I have a table with documents having keys like:

```
name, created_at, [likes_to_eat], [likes_to_drink]
```

The keys between brackets are optional (may or may not be in the document).

I would like to fetch all documents from this table that don't have `likes_to_eat` and `likes_to_drink` keys. I've found in the docs that I could do this:

```
r.table('users').filter(
    lambda user: not user.has_fields('likes_to_eat', 'likes_to_drink')
).run(conn)
```

But `has_fields` puts an AND between the keys, whilst I need an OR (so filter a user whether he hasn't got `likes_to_eat` OR `likes_to_drink` OR both).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r.table('users').filter(
    lambda user: ~user.has_fields('likes_to_eat', 'likes_to_drink')
).run(conn)
```

Edit: Made a mistake and used contains intead of has_fields.

Comment: I tried this with JS in my RethinkDB web console and it gives me the following error: `RqlRuntimeError: Cannot convert OBJECT to SEQUENCE in:`. The query was: `r.db('db').table('tb').filter(function(a) {return a.contains('col');})`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: My bad, contains is to check if an array contains an element, not if an object contains a key. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I was closer than I thought. I was negating using `not` instead of `~` (like @neumino suggested). So here's the working snippet:

```
r.table('users').filter(
    lambda user: ~user.has_fields('likes_to_eat', 'likes_to_drink')
).run(conn)
```

`has_fields` actually puts an OR between the given arguments.